# WP job Manager, how to automatically add job title with post ID in the permalink/slug on single job via admin

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using WP Job Manager.

I would like the permalink/slug for each job to automatically use the job title and appended the slug with the post ID

important: i need this work when added a job via the admin

so:

Job title:
Graphic Designer London Uk

becomes
`jobsite.com/job/graphic-designer-london-uk`

then once published becomes, added the post ID
`jobsite.com/job/graphic-designer-london-uk-1234`

for some reason i can only get it automatically do 1 or the other, not both

so it is either

`jobsite.com/job/graphic-designer-london-uk`

or this

`jobsite.com/job/1234`

I added this

```php
function custom_job_post_type_link( $post_id, $post ) {

        // don't add the id if it's already part of the slug
        $permalink = $post->post_name;
        if ( strpos( $permalink, strval( $post_id ) ) ) {
            return;
        }
        
        // unhook this function to prevent infinite looping
        remove_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

    // add the id to the slug
        $permalink .= '-' . $post_id;
    
        // update the post slug
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_name' => $permalink
        ));

        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
}
add_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

but this only adds the post ID on when submitting a job on the front end, not via the backend (admin)

when adding a job via the admin, the permalink/slug auto populates with just the post ID and has to  be manually changed